# Optional relationship to more than one table in Entity Framework ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, orm

I'm trying to build a ASP.net MVC application. I'm having trouble making some kind of relation with data annotations.

I have 3 tables, `Overhours`, `Accountings`, `Vacations`. Every `Overhour` record can have 1 `Accounting` or `Vacation` record but it's optional. So, it doesn't need to have to have one. Here is my `Overhour` model:

```
public class Overhour
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int OverhourId { get; set; }

    ....

    public int? AccountingId { get; set; }
    public virtual Accounting Accounting { get; set; }

    public int? VacationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Vacation Vacation { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have both `Vacation` and `Accounting` record deleted when i delete my `Overhour` record (if there is any). When i use it like this, cascading delete gets disabled.

I tried this:

```
public class Overhour
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int OverhourId { get; set; }

    ....

    public virtual Accounting Accounting { get; set; }

    public virtual Vacation Vacation { get; set; }
}
```

Cascading delete works but Entity Framework creates fields like "Accounting_AccountingId", also it becomes required. Those shouldn't be required.

Last thing i tried was this:

```
public class Overhour
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int OverhourId { get; set; }

    ....

    public int AccountingId { get; set; }
    public virtual Accounting Accounting { get; set; }

    public int VacationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Vacation Vacation { get; set; }
}
```

But this time it gives me an error like this:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY xxx constraint on table xxx may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints

I'm pretty confused, what am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

DELETE CASCADE doesn't work like that. If you delete `Overhour`, nothing else will nor should be deleted. It works in the opposite direction. If `Accounting` is a required dependent, and you delete the `Accounting` instance that's attached to `Overhour`, then `Overhour` should also, then, be deleted. That won't occur if the foreign key is nullable, as then it will be set to DELETE SET NULL, instead. Either way, though, deleting `Overhour` will never have any effect on `Accounting` or `Vacation` instances.

**UPDATE**

Creating a one-to-one, which it seems like you need here, is relatively easy in this scenario, since one side of the relationship is optional. All you need is:

```
public class Overhour
{
    ...

    public int? AccountingId { get; set; } // optional
    public virtual Accounting Accounting { get; set; }
}

public class Accounting
{
    ...

    public int OverhourId { get; set; } // required
    public virtual Overhour Overhour { get; set; }
}
```

With that, deleting the `Overhour` will cascade and delete the associated `Accounting` as well, since it's dependent on `Overhour`.

Things only get complicated when both sides of the relationship are required. Then, you must use fluent config to set one as the principal and one as the dependent, since EF can't make this decision on its own at that point.

Comment: Actually cascade delete works in my second example. I'm so confused. So, what should i do in my situtation? Should i delete related records by myself? Because i need to delete accounting and vacation records when i delete an overhour record.

Comment: Well, the problem is how you're treating them. By default, this will create a one-to-many, i.e. `Overhour` has one `Accounting` and `Accounting` has many `Overhour`. That's why it doesn't delete `Accounting` in this scenario, because it may still have valid uses outside of this one `Overhour` instance. If you truly want `Accounting` bound to a particular `Overhour` instance, then your relationship should be one-to-one.

Comment: I'm so lost, i think i need to read few more stuff about Fluent Api.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Thing is, accounting doesn't need to have an overhour record too. So, both sides are optional i guess. Maybe that's why it's not working. Probably there isn't a relation type like this?

Comment: You can have a one-to-one where both sides are optional. However, the same caveat with both being required applies: you must use fluent config to clue EF into which is dependent and which is the principal. That said, I'm unsure why you would expect there to be a delete cascade in either direction. If `Accounting` doesn't depend on a particular `Overhour`, then it logically should not be removed just because `Overhour` is deleted. If it doesn't have value outside of it's relationship to `Overhour`, the `Overhour` *should* be required.

Comment: Accounting doesn't need to have an Overhour, it can exist without any other record, same goes for Overhour, that's why it's optional on both sides. After trying every possible Fluent Api configuration, i basically gave up on cascade delete on this model, i will just use classic delete for now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, like I said, if you have a one-to-one that's optional on both sides, deleting one will never delete the other. You can apply whatever configuration you like and that will never change, because it's just how relational databases work. DELETE CASCADE isn't there just to make your life easier; it's an integrity maintainer. The database will not apply it unless integrity is at stake, which it never is with an optional relationship.